# Having a NGINX redirect loop which i cant figure out

Tags: nginx, web-server

I have this configuration running on nginx server and im running into redirect loop. Application behind this is prestashop 1.7.x.x.

Unfortunately, i cant figure out the reason...
Can someone explain please? :)

Obiviously, i have changed some parameters in the config but it should not be problem.

nginx -t is not giving errors.

Im new to nginx and i followed this guide: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-prestashop-on-ubuntu/

```
# Redirect HTTP -> HTTPS
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com example.com;

include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# Redirect WWW -> NON WWW

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name www.example.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
include snippets/ssl.conf;

return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name example.com;

root /var/www/html/example.com;
index index.php;

# SSL parameters
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
include snippets/ssl.conf;
include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

# log files
access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

}
```

Comment: The nginx configuration that you have shown does not contain a redirect loop. Make sure nginx is actually running with this configuration and that you have cleared your browser cache. After that check your web application.

Comment: Hey. I've tried clearing browser cache and nginx is running. I got to install the application via webinstall and there was no problem doing that.
If i bring up the developer tools and monitor network while loading the page, it shows about 13 redirects... And it's looping. What could be the further options?

I've read, that i could recreate .htaccess file from admin panel, but i cant access it  either :D

Comment: nginx doesn't support `.htaccess` files so that is not going to be a solution anyway. But a typical reason for this to happen is when your application is configured to run on the domain  `www.example.com` and is redirecting your requests accordingly, but your web server configuration is redirecting in the opposite direction. Solution: Temporarily disable the redirect from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` in nginx and configure your web server to also show your site on the www URL. Then use the admin panel and reconfigure your site so it stops using the www domain name

Comment: From what to see in the part of the nginx config You posted there is a possible redirect loop if You would use HTTP/1.0 without sending host header. But as You are using a browser with a dev console available nowadays You probably are using HTTP/1.1 or newer which should loop from what You posted.  So without seeing full configuration and/or full information from network-analyzer tab of browsers dev tools nothin more to say (but @HBruijn comment sounds very reasonable and You should see it's traces in the dev console network analyzer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

In my point of View, you double your config,

- Port 80 Section; You are listening on 80 for (www.)domain.com
- Port 443 First, you are listening on 443 for www.domain.com
  -- Here you are using domain.com have to be used
- Port 443 Second, you are listening on 443 for domain.com
  -- Here you have your load
  ---- but WHY? In my Mind you complex your config with no benefit...?

---

In my Point of view, you should give this a try:

```
# Redirect HTTP -> HTTPS
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com example.com;

include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
#here you already tell the browser to use example instead of any other
}


server {
#anyway, if really www is still here we rewrite it permanently
if ($host = 'www.example.com' ) {
rewrite ^ https://example.com$uri permanent;
}

listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

root /var/www/html/example.com;
index index.php;

# SSL parameters
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
include snippets/ssl.conf;
include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

# log files
access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

} #i am not sure, if this must be removed
```

i hope i could help you